# Store results of a sql query into variables access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have sql query which returns the some of some fields based on three criteria.

1. LOC field have a string "Alipore"
2. Date is greater than and equal to than a variable sdate which gets the value from a textbox on a form.
3. Date is less than and equal to than a variable edate which gets the value from a textbox on a form.

but I am getting an error "two few parameter 2" error.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sqlMax As String
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim startd, endd As String

    startd = Me.txtsdate.Value

    endd = Me.txtedate.Value

    sqlMax = "SELECT Sum(Salesdata.FOOD) AS SumOfFOOD, Sum(Salesdata.LIQUORS) AS SumOfLIQUORS, Sum(Salesdata.SMARTPORTION) AS SumOfSMARTPORTION, Sum(Salesdata.[SP TAKEAWAY]) AS [SumOfSP TAKEAWAY]," _
     & "Sum(Salesdata.TAKEAWAY) AS SumOfTAKEAWAY, Sum(Salesdata.TAX_KKCESS02) AS SumOfTAX_KKCESS02, Sum(Salesdata.TAX_SBC020) AS SumOfTAX_SBC020, Sum(Salesdata.TAX_SERVICECHARGE) AS SumOfTAX_SERVICECHARGE," _
     & "Sum(Salesdata.TAX_VAT145) AS SumOfTAX_VAT145, Sum(Salesdata.AMEX) AS SumOfAMEX, Sum(Salesdata.CASH) AS SumOfCASH, Sum(Salesdata.MASTERCARD) AS SumOfMASTERCARD, Sum(Salesdata.VISA) AS SumOfVISA, Sum(Salesdata.OTHERS) AS SumOfOTHERS," _
     & "Sum(Salesdata.Vcloud) AS SumOfVcloud, Sum(Salesdata.MANAGERAC) AS SumOfMANAGERAC FROM Salesdata" _
     & "WHERE (((Salesdata.Loc) = 'Alipore'))" _
     & "HAVING (((Salesdata.DATE)>=" & startd & " And (Salesdata.DATE)<=" & endd & "));"
```

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMax, dbOpenDynaset)

```
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMax)

    result = rs.Fields(0)

    MsgBox result

    Set rs = Nothing

    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Did you intend `startD` to be a `Variant`? Also some SQL variants, dates need to have `#` surrounding the dates. E.g. #1/1/2017# Might be that

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Now I have an error when run from vba err# 3141, but runs fine as a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh god I found it, it's so simple. There is a space required before where that's why it run in access but when I copied it into VBA and restructured the sql statement.

it should be

& "  WHERE (((Salesdata.Loc) = 'Alipore'))" _

instead of

& "WHERE (((Salesdata.Loc) = 'Alipore'))" _